# Time complexity for calculating the $LPS$ array (failure function) in KMP algorithm preprocessing

Tags: substrings, string-matching

I'm studying the Knuth Morris Pratt pattern searching algorithm from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kmp-algorithm-for-pattern-searching/). I want to know the order of computing the $lps$ array in this algorithm - that is the array of longest proper prefixes that are also suffix. I studied the Wikipedia page for this algorithm and it says this part is of $O(m)$ - $m$ is the length of the pattern being searched. I just don't understand why.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've copied below the wikipedia algorithm for computing the LPS array (which is usually called the failure function because in the main KMP algorithm you refer to this table whenver there's a failed match). They denote $T[]$ where you use $LPS[]$

> algorithm kmp_table:
>       input:
>           an array of characters, W (the word to be analyzed)
>           an array of integers, T (the table to be filled)
>       output:
>           nothing (but during operation, it populates the table)
>
> ```
> define variables:
>     an integer, pos ← 1 (the current position we are computing in T)
>     an integer, cnd ← 0 (the zero-based index in W of the next character of the current candidate substring)
>
> let T[0] ← -1
>
> while pos < length(W) do
>     if W[pos] = W[cnd] then
>         let T[pos] ← T[cnd]
>     else
>         let T[pos] ← cnd
>         let cnd ← T[cnd] (to increase performance)
>         while cnd >= 0 and W[pos] <> W[cnd] do
>             let cnd ← T[cnd]
>     let pos ← pos + 1, cnd ← cnd + 1
>
> let T[pos] ← cnd (only need when all word occurrences searched)
> ```

The running time will be dictated by how many times "cnd" gets assigned to. The while loop inside the for loop ($pos$) might make you think the algorithm is $O(m^2)$ but as you learned it is $O(m)$.

Inspect how $cnd$ may change during one step of the for loop; it can either increase by +1, or it can decrease inside the while loop. And when it decreases, it decreases by *at least* 1, since $T[]$ satisfies $T[x]<x$ for all $x$ ("proper" in the definition of LPS). Since $cnd$ can increase only by +1 and there are $m$ steps in the for loop, this means the overall increase is bounded by $+m$.  You might visualize each change to $cnd$ as a stair of integer height, with upstairs and downstairs representing increases and decreases to $cnd$; the upstairs are all height 1, and the downstairs are each height at least 1.  Because the overall height never falls below 0 (that is the termination condition for the while loop), you can bound the total number of stairs by $2m$; there are at most $m$ "up" stairs and there can't be more "down" stairs than up stairs since their height is $\geq 1$.

To put another way, this is basically a twist on the saying "what goes up most come down"; here we have "what comes down must have gone up before"

Comment: Awesome explanation!